# spring boot deploy on tomcat， error jndi error

Tags: java, spring-boot

When my spring boot application is deployed on tomcat， it's just about springmvc project， it could use json to communicate with the Server and it doesn't need to communicate with mysql db. The question is that I can't run success.

the log is :

> [DEBUG]2018-02-26
>   11:11:12[|||||||]org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment|Replacing
>   PropertySource 'servletContextInitParams' with
>   'servletContextInitParams'| [DEBUG]2018-02-26
>   11:11:13[|||||||]org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate|Looking up JNDI
>   object with name [java:comp/env/logging.register-shutdown-hook]|
>   [DEBUG]2018-02-26
>   11:11:13[|||||||]org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorDelegate|Converted
>   JNDI name [java:comp/env/logging.register-shutdown-hook] not found -
>   trying original name [logging.register-shutdown-hook].
>   javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name
>   [logging.register-shutdown-hook] is not bound in this Context. Unable
>   to find [logging.register-shutdown-hook].| [DEBUG]2018-02-26
>   11:11:13[|||||||]org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate|Looking up JNDI
>   object with name [logging.register-shutdown-hook]| [DEBUG]2018-02-26
>   11:11:13[|||||||]org.springframework.jndi.JndiPropertySource|JNDI
>   lookup for name [logging.register-shutdown-hook] threw NamingException
>   with message: Name [logging.register-shutdown-hook] is not bound in
>   this Context. Unable to find [logging.register-shutdown-hook]..
>   Returning null.| [DEBUG]2018-02-26
>   11:11:13[|||||||]org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate|Looking up JNDI
>   object with name [java:comp/env/logging.register_shutdown_hook]|
>   [DEBUG]2018-02-26
>   11:11:13[|||||||]org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorDelegate|Converted
>   JNDI name [java:comp/env/logging.register_shutdown_hook] not found -
>   trying original name [logging.register_shutdown_hook].
>   javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name
>   [logging.register_shutdown_hook] is not bound in this Context. Unable
>   to find [logging.register_shutdown_hook].| [DEBUG]2018-02-26
>   11:11:13[|||||||]org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate|Looking up JNDI
>   object with name [logging.register_shutdown_hook]| [DEBUG]2018-02-26
>   11:11:13[|||||||]org.springframework.jndi.JndiPropertySource|JNDI
>   lookup for name [logging.register_shutdown_hook] threw NamingException
>   with message: Name [logging.register_shutdown_hook] is not bound in
>   this Context. Unable to find [logging.register_shutdown_hook]..
>   Returning null.| [DEBUG]2018-02-26
>   11:11:13[|||||||]org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate|Looking up JNDI
>   object with name [java:comp/env/logging_register-shutdown-hook]|
>   [DEBUG]2018-02-26
>   11:11:13[|||||||]org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorDelegate|Converted
>   JNDI name [java:comp/env/logging_register-shutdown-hook] not found -
>   trying original name [logging_register-shutdown-hook].
>   javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name
>   [logging_register-shutdown-hook] is not bound in this Context. Unable
>   to find [logging_register-shutdown-hook].| [DEBUG]2018-02-26
>   11:11:13[|||||||]org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate|Looking up JNDI
>   object with name [logging_register-shutdown-hook]| [DEBUG]2018-02-26
>   11:11:13[|||||||]org.springframework.jndi.JndiPropertySource|JNDI
>   lookup for name [logging_register-shutdown-hook] threw NamingException
>   with message: Name [logging_register-shutdown-hook] is not bound in
>   this Context. Unable to find [logging_register-shutdown-hook]..
>   Returning null.| [DEBUG]2018-02-26
>   11:11:13[|||||||]org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate|Looking up JNDI
>   object with name [java:comp/env/loggingRegisterShutdownHook]|
>   [DEBUG]2018-02-26
>   11:11:13[|||||||]org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorDelegate|Converted
>   JNDI name [java:comp/env/loggingRegisterShutdownHook] not found -
>   trying original name [loggingRegisterShutdownHook].
>   javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [loggingRegisterShutdownHook]
>   is not bound in this Context. Unable to find
>   [loggingRegisterShutdownHook].| [DEBUG]2018-02-26
>   11:11:13[|||||||]org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate|Looking up JNDI
>   object with name [loggingRegisterShutdownHook]| [DEBUG]2018-02-26
>   11:11:13[|||||||]org.springframework.jndi.JndiPropertySource|JNDI
>   lookup for name [loggingRegisterShutdownHook] threw NamingException
>   with message: Name [loggingRegisterShutdownHook] is not bound in this
>   Context. Unable to find [loggingRegisterShutdownHook].. Returning
>   null.| [DEBUG]2018-02-26
>   11:11:13[|||||||]org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate|Looking up JNDI
>   object with name [java:comp/env/loggingregistershutdownhook]|
>   [DEBUG]2018-02-26
>   11:11:13[|||||||]org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorDelegate|Converted
>   JNDI name [java:comp/env/loggingregistershutdownhook] not found -
>   trying original name [loggingregistershutdownhook].
>   javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [loggingregistershutdownhook]
>   is not bound in this Context. Unable to find
>   [loggingregistershutdownhook].| [DEBUG]2018-02-26
>   11:11:13[|||||||]org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate|Looking up JNDI
>   object with name [loggingregistershutdownhook]| [DEBUG]2018-02-26
>   11:11:13[|||||||]org.springframework.jndi.JndiPropertySource|JNDI
>   lookup for name [loggingregistershutdownhook] threw NamingException
>   with message: Name [loggingregistershutdownhook] is not bound in this
>   Context. Unable to find [loggingregistershutdownhook].. Returning
>   null.| [DEBUG]2018-02-26
>   11:11:13[|||||||]org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate|Looking up JNDI
>   object with name [java:comp/env/LOGGING.REGISTER-SHUTDOWN-HOOK]|
>   [DEBUG]2018-02-26
>   11:11:13[|||||||]org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorDelegate|Converted
>   JNDI name [java:comp/env/LOGGING.REGISTER-SHUTDOWN-HOOK] not found -
>   trying original name [LOGGING.REGISTER-SHUTDOWN-HOOK].
>   javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name
>   [LOGGING.REGISTER-SHUTDOWN-HOOK] is not bound in this Context. Unable
>   to find [LOGGING.REGISTER-SHUTDOWN-HOOK].| [DEBUG]2018-02-26
>   11:11:13[|||||||]org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate|Looking up JNDI
>   object with name [LOGGING.REGISTER-SHUTDOWN-HOOK]| [DEBUG]2018-02-26
>   11:11:13[|||||||]org.springframework.jndi.JndiPropertySource|JNDI
>   lookup for name [LOGGING.REGISTER-SHUTDOWN-HOOK] threw NamingException
>   with message: Name [LOGGING.REGISTER-SHUTDOWN-HOOK] is not bound in
>   this Context. Unable to find [LOGGING.REGISTER-SHUTDOWN-HOOK]..
>   Returning null.| [DEBUG]2018-02-26
>   11:11:13[|||||||]org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate|Looking up JNDI
>   object with name [java:comp/env/LOGGING.REGISTER_SHUTDOWN_HOOK]|
>   [DEBUG]2018-02-26
>   11:11:13[|||||||]org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorDelegate|Converted
>   JNDI name [java:comp/env/LOGGING.REGISTER_SHUTDOWN_HOOK] not found -
>   trying original name [LOGGING.REGISTER_SHUTDOWN_HOOK].
>   javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name
>   [LOGGING.REGISTER_SHUTDOWN_HOOK] is not bound in this Context. Unable
>   to find [LOGGING.REGISTER_SHUTDOWN_HOOK].| [DEBUG]2018-02-26
>   11:11:13[|||||||]org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate|Looking up JNDI
>   object with name [LOGGING.REGISTER_SHUTDOWN_HOOK]| [DEBUG]2018-02-26
>   11:11:13[|||||||]org.springframework.jndi.JndiPropertySource|JNDI
>   lookup for name [LOGGING.REGISTER_SHUTDOWN_HOOK] threw NamingException
>   with message: Name [LOGGING.REGISTER_SHUTDOWN_HOOK] is not bound in
>   this Context. Unable to find [LOGGING.REGISTER_SHUTDOWN_HOOK]..
>   Returning null.| [DEBUG]2018-02-26
>   11:11:13[|||||||]org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate|Looking up JNDI
>   object with name [java:comp/env/LOGGING_REGISTER-SHUTDOWN-HOOK]|
>   [DEBUG]2018-02-26
>   11:11:13[|||||||]org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorDelegate|Converted
>   JNDI name [java:comp/env/LOGGING_REGISTER-SHUTDOWN-HOOK] not found -
>   trying original name [LOGGING_REGISTER-SHUTDOWN-HOOK].
>   javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name
>   [LOGGING_REGISTER-SHUTDOWN-HOOK] is not bound in this Context. Unable
>   to find [LOGGING_REGISTER-SHUTDOWN-HOOK].| [DEBUG]2018-02-26
>   11:11:13[|||||||]org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate|Looking up JNDI
>   object with name [LOGGING_REGISTER-SHUTDOWN-HOOK]| [DEBUG]2018-02-26
>   11:11:13[|||||||]org.springframework.jndi.JndiPropertySource|JNDI
>   lookup for name [LOGGING_REGISTER-SHUTDOWN-HOOK] threw NamingException
>   with message: Name [LOGGING_REGISTER-SHUTDOWN-HOOK] is not bound in
>   this Context. Unable to find [LOGGING_REGISTER-SHUTDOWN-HOOK]..
>   Returning null.| [DEBUG]2018-02-26
>   11:11:13[|||||||]org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate|Looking up JNDI
>   object with name [java:comp/env/LOGGINGREGISTERSHUTDOWNHOOK]|
>   [DEBUG]2018-02-26
>   11:11:13[|||||||]org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorDelegate|Converted
>   JNDI name [java:comp/env/LOGGINGREGISTERSHUTDOWNHOOK] not found -
>   trying original name [LOGGINGREGISTERSHUTDOWNHOOK].
>   javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [LOGGINGREGISTERSHUTDOWNHOOK]
>   is not bound in this Context. Unable to find
>   [LOGGINGREGISTERSHUTDOWNHOOK].|

Answer (score 0):

As per the logs, it seems spring boot is trying to find "logging.register-shutdown-hook" in your application.properties file.

Did you define this in your application.properties file? If not can you try to define this property and run the application again.